# Best way to access same string list from both python and C++ programs

Tags: python, c++, string, file

I have a set of string messages I'm passing to a named pipe through a C++ program. A python program reads the named pipe and executes commands according to the message.

What is the best way to store the string messages so that both python and C++ programs can access them? Right now I'm declaring them as string values in both the C++ and Python programs, but this is duplicating the string messages and causing issues like having to edit/compile both programs if I want to change a message. Another way is to store them in a common file and have both programs read it, but this seems a bit cumbersome. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: How are the C++ and Python programs related?

Comment: They aren't a lot related except the C++ program can access the python code if needed.